# How do I create clickable areas on an image within a webpage with javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, interactive, clickable, areas

I want to create a webpage displaying an image that has areas on it that can be clicked to do various things like playing sound, displaying text, linking to other pages. The only problem is I have no idea what I need to use within javascript to do so. The area need not be complicated, just a simple geometric shape.

What sort of tools should I be looking at in Javascript to do achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get started here and read the documentation http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at `<map></map>` tag in HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp
It should accomplish what you want to do.